# How do i access the username of user logged in with google in Django from user model

Tags: python, django, database

How to access the username of user logged in with google in django all-auth from the user model

> how can i access the user name of the logged in user with google from user model
> for example

```
{% for i in user %}
    {{i.socialaccount_set.all.0.extra_data.name}}//is there a way to acces the user name in this way
{% endfor %}
```

My views.py

```
def leaderBoard(request):
points= Points.objects.all().order_by("-score")
context = {"user": result}
return render(request, "Main/lb.html", context)
```

My model.py

```
class Points(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    score = models.BigIntegerField()
```

my htmlfile

```
<div class="leaderboard-table">
    {% for i in user %}
    <div class="board-item">
      <div>1</div>
      <div>
        {% if i.socialaccount_set.all.0.get_avatar_url %}
        <img src="{{i.socialaccount_set.all.0.get_avatar_url}}" />
        {{i}}//how to access the user name of the googleuser
      </div>
      <div>Test's Taken - 30</div>
      <div>{{i.score}} Points</div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Is `i.email` not working?

Comment: no that not working and i need username

Answer (score 0):

With the username, I assume you want to access Django's default username field for that particular user.

You can access it like this.

```
{% for i in user %}
    {{i.username}}
{% endfor %}
```

Also, one more thing I noticed is that your view is missing `result` data which you are appending to your context dictionary.